# T SQL Table Valued function SQL46010 :: Incorrect syntax near declare

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get the above error when i try to save this to the SQL Server db.  Any clue why? the Select distinct query works without issue

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetSeqsInAllSegments]
(
)
RETURNS @ret  TABLE
(
    SequenceID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    insert @ret
     select distinct SequenceID from dbo.Segments where SequenceID in 
    ( 
        select  SequenceID from dbo.Segments
        group by SequenceID
        having count(DISTINCT SegmentID) = ( select count(*) from ( select distinct SegmentID from dbo.Segments ) AS A
    ))
    RETURN
END
```

UPDATE:  It only throws that error inside of SQL Server Data Tools 2015.  Does not do it in SQL management studio.

Comment: But there is no  `declare` in your code.

Comment: What is your input and expected output? Looks like for simple requirement you have complex query

Comment: Are you certain that's the only script you have?  There isn't a `DECLARE` anywhere in your code.  Perhaps something above or below your script is causing issues?

Comment: Iknow, bug in sql server data tools

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use SQL Management studio, it only throws that error inside of SQL Server Data Tools 2015. Does not do it in SQL management studio.